# Float Number mathematical operation

Tags: math, floating-point, tcl

I have a .txt file as output from a program that contains some values of interest. The problem is that in certain cases these values have a strange format and i'm not able to apply mathematical operations on them.

E.g: My file contains these numbers:

```
-2.55622-3   
-0.31-2
-3.225-2
...
```

These numbers in a normal math format should be:

```
-2.55622e-03
-0.31e-02
-3.225e-02
```

OF course, if i try to sum these values, this is the error:

```
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
```

How can i operate with my original values? I have really no ideas.
Please remember that i can't change the values format of my .txt file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:

```
% exec cat file
-2.55622-3   
-0.31-2
-3.225-2
42
foo
% set fh [open "file" r]
% while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
  puts -nonewline "\"$line\"\t=> "
  if {! [regsub {[-+]\d+$} [string trim $line] {e&} num]} {set num $line}
  puts -nonewline "$num\t=> "
  puts [expr {$num + 0}]
}
"-2.55622-3   " => -2.55622e-3  => -0.00255622
"-0.31-2"       => -0.31e-2     => -0.0031
"-3.225-2"      => -3.225e-2    => -0.03225
"42"    => 42   => 42
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
"foo"   => foo  => %
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to regsub digits with pattern `(\d+.\d+)`.

```
set fp [open "somefile.txt" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
foreach line $data {
set e "e"
set number [ regexp -all -inline {(\d+.\d+)} $line ]
regsub -all {(\d+.\d+)} $number "$number$e" number
```

}

For example read file and split by lines.

```
set e "e"
```

Find number by:

```
set number [ regexp -all -inline {(\d+.\d+)} $line ]
```

then replace

```
regsub -all {(\d+.\d+)} $number "$number$e" number
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution since OP didn't mention that these are the only kind of numbers present in the file. What I mean is that you could have a line like `2.3` and your code would convert it to `2.3e` which is incorrect even if `2.3-4` would be correctly converted to `2.3e-4`.